# Mod_rewrite question - my brain is fried!

Tags: mod-rewrite

Can someone helpe me with this mod_write issue?
I want to rewrite this:

www.mydomain.org/site/767-title.php

to

www.mydomain.org/index.php?e=767

Thanks!!

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^/site/(\d+)-title.php /index.php?e=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/site/([^/\.]+)-title.php /index.php?e=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```